# Por que ter uma pontuação alta no site Stack overflow?

Tags: debate

Quais os benefícios que isso traz a vida de alguém?

> Implementation 'com.implementando.minha:pergunta:1.0.1'

Tem que se ter ponto pra isso ou aqui... o site é pra ajudar a esclarecer dúvidas ou pra ficar ganhando pontos e reputação? Agora, se você me disser que grandes empresarios do ramo da tecnologia contrata pessoas por aqui e para isso precisam ter muitos pontos ou uma boa reputação pra isso, então eu tiro o chapéu e dou o braço a torcer pra vocês.

Comment: Qual o motivo da pergunta, dê contexto ao que quer saber para uma resposta melhor.

Comment: O que significa `Implementation 'com.implementando.minha:pergunta:1.0.1'`?

Comment: Você é americano né? ou melhor, Você não é brasileiro né? kkkkkkkk significa sarcasmo. É só bobagem mesmo....

Comment: É possível adicionar algo mais para a pergunta ser mais construtiva? Pode argumentar mais sobre o que deseja saber ou propor?

Comment: Se tivesse lido o tour do site ou tivesse passado na central de ajuda, já saberia o motivo.

Comment: Era pra isso ser alguma piada com Java? Acho que peguei a referência.

Comment: Não serve pra nada.

Comment: Andre os pontos não valem nada, eles apenas são um reflexo da sua participação. Se vc participa frequentemente e com resposta de qualidade vc ganha pontos, com esses pontos vc vai se tornando um tipo de moderador dentro da comunidade, podendo votar, comentar, excluir coisas, editar etc..., mas se vc responde com qualquer merda que vem da sua cabeça apenas baseado em "achismo", sem fonte, etc. vc acaba sofrendo retalhações com downvotes. Não é difícil de entender não é?!

Comment: Tirando o contexto, o título da pergunta é uma grande dúvida para muitos usuários.

Comment: Só para os que não entendem a filosofia de funcionamento do site @bio. Depois que se entende(com um tempinho de uso, claro), essa duvida deixa de existir.

Comment: @Articuno, sim, usuários novatos. Como disse muitas vezes por aqui...

Comment: @AndreAlas *"empresarios do ramo da tecnologia contrata pessoas por aqui "*  acho que isso é verdade, se você quer uma resposta direta, principalmente mundo afora. Muitas vagas que vejo por ai pedem do candidato referências de sua *"presença na rede"*, ou seja, projetos no Github, Stackoverflow, Codeplex, Codeproject, etc. E num mundo cada vez mais globalizado, onde você pode contratar alguém de outro ponto qualquer do mundo, ou ainda para um trabalho remoto, uma ótima maneira de checar as referências é ver sua contribuição nas redes, não tem empresa que olham até mesmo seu `facebook`? :P

Answer (score 14):

Vida é algo muito amplo. Certamente tem efeitos psicológicos. De forma geral os animais gostam de ser premiados por algo que fizeram, de ter reconhecimento, não importa muito como. Um tapinha nas coisas já vale. Qualquer coisa que a pessoa ganhe de retorno de outras pessoas vale, as pessoas são motivadas principalmente por reconhecimento. A pontuação é uma forma de reconhecimento.

Do quê, cada um pode ver de uma forma, pode ser só que a pessoa participa e contribui ou contribuiu na comunidade. A pontuação indica que a pessoa faz postagens interessantes. Claro que precisa ver como a pessoa obteve, se foi com perguntas com respostas, se foi com muita resposta para pouca reputação, e algo até mais complexo, se foi dado por outras pessoas qualificadas ou veio basicamente de quem perguntou e quer retribuir pela ajuda, mesmo que a resposta seja ruim ou até mesmo errada.

Não pela reputação em si, mas por participar muito para ganhar esta reputação é possível usar para alguma coisa. Há quem valorizará na hora de oferecer um emprego. Responder no SO(pt) serve como currículo mais realista que um formal. Pode abrir portas.

Por causa da minha participação aqui acabei recebendo um [prêmio da Microsoft](https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/PublicProfile/5002397) no ano passado (espero renovar semana que vem). E este prêmio abriu portas para eu fazer uma série de coisas, como [palestrar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-lVjZVoQViE&feature=youtu.be&t=19m44s), participar de eventos, ter uma rede de contatos interessantes, comecei ter audiência nas [minhas redes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/maniero?tab=profile) (que preciso começar usar mais), receber convites para fazer algumas atividades, algo que não posso falar ainda, e já recebi ofertas de emprego e negócios por causa disto. Certamente meu passe está mais valorizado.

Fiz tudo sem esperar isto, aconteceu bem sem querer, tanto que a Microsoft me procurou por conta própria, não foi eu que corri atrás, não fui indicado por ninguém, foi até surpreendente e nem conhecia direito o programa.

E tem outras que eu nem lembrei agora. Mas querer ter uma boa pontuação não deveria ser o objetivo. Porque a avaliação do conteúdo é feito por pessoas que podem considerá-la, e se o conteúdo for ruim de nada adianta. Tem usuários que possuem boa pontuação, mas com bastante postagem errada. Não considere a pontuação como atestado de competência da pessoa.

> Tem que se ter ponto pra isso ou aqui... o site é pra ajudar a esclarecer dúvidas ou pra ficar ganhando pontos e reputação?

O site é para ambos, por que acha que um exclui o outro? A pontuação é um reconhecimento e incentivo para as pessoas ajudarem.

> Agora, se você me disser que grandes empresarios do ramo da tecnologia contrata pessoas por aqui

Isto parte de uma premissa errada, então nem sei como responder, mas estaria havendo algum recalque na pergunta?

> e para isso precisam ter muitos pontos ou uma boa reputação pra isso, então eu tiro o chapéu e dou o braço a torcer pra vocês.

E já mostrei que é possível conseguir algo, depende de cada um. Poderia ter feito a crítica mais abertamente.

## Crítica à obtenção de reputação

Quem acha isto errado, e é um direito a pessoa achar o que quiser enquanto não esteja prejudicando alguém, pode mostrar que acredita nisto.

Comece a se alimentar só para ingerir nutrientes, não queira nada com sabor. Se afaste principalmente do sal e açúcar que prejudicam você. Parece de escutar música, assistir áudio-visuais e ler livros (pelo menos os de ficção, já que a linha de pensamento adotada na pergunta é do "utilismo") por gasta-se muito tempo com isso sem dar emprego em grandes empresas (ah, tá bom...), mas não precisa de um grande emprego porque só irá comprar o mínimo pra sobreviver, e esquecerá até do que é grátis (em tese), como o sexo e outras relações humanas porque essas coisas não trazem emprego pra ninguém.

A pontuação recebida traz o mesmo que tudo isso traz. Eu já vi gente que até se acha equilibrada, sóbria pensar mais ou menos assim, dizendo que as pessoas ficam gastando o tempo aqui pra conseguir pontos falsos aqui, e logo quem deveria incentivar as pessoas participarem, talvez por isso não apareça mais por aqui.

E tem quem critica os que querem pontuação, mas segue ganhando-a, quase a qualquer custo, e não faz nada para evitar o ganho de pontos, e não usa seus pontos para ajudar destacar conteúdo bom, ou incentivar outras pessoas, aí o recalque é certo. Os pontos são tão importantes que existe até este tipo de comportamento. Eu mesmo posso não não ter uma relação boa com a pontuação, pelo menos em alguns momentos (nos sites da rede em inglês até tinha mais porque a votação não era tão tendenciosa como é aqui), mas eu reconheço que tem isso.

Quando alguém reclama das pessoas quererem pontuação mostra o quanto o assunto é importante, porque o oposto do amor é o desprezo e não o ódio. Mas desprezo real, não discurso. Quando é dito que despreza na verdade é ódio, que é só o outro lado do amor, geralmente não correspondido.

Comment: De uma maneira geral as coisas tendem a acontecer de uma forma ou de outra. O fato de ter acontecido algo tão maravilhoso com você não significa que pode acontecer novamente com você ou com outra pessoa. (Mas pode ser que aconteça> quem sabe !?) . Não significa nada pra ninguém a não ser para você mesmo e pro seu núcleo familiar.... Bom de qualquer forma, eu não dou a mínima pra esse site. Pra quem exclui fulano ou fulano exclui ciclano. O que eu quero mesmo é as respostas porque a verdade é que uma pergunta não responde a outra.

Comment: @AndreAlas não é verdade que você não dá a mínima. A energia gasta postando e querendo provar seu ponto (apesar de estar funcionando às avessas) deixa isso claro. Provavelmente quando não der a mínima vai só consultar mesmo, e quando aparecer a pergunta/resposta no seu engine favorito de pesquisas. Sobre a pergunta, cai no que chamamos de "principalmente baseado em opiniões", creio eu. Cada um tem seu motivo, não tem resposta exata. O site está aí, cada um usa para o que achar melhor (seja aprender, ensinar, criar polêmica, tirar dúvidas, criar novas dúvidas, e até perder tempo se quiser).

Comment: Mas, pense no lado bom, já conseguiu algum resultado movimentando pessoas para darem um feedback. Já não passou em branco, ao menos! ; )

Comment: Cada um enxerga como quiser, se acha que foi sorte, então boa sorte na sua vida, você vai precisar. Outras pessoas trabalham duro para que as coisas aconteçam. Em geral pessoas apaixonadas costumam se dar uma hora ou outra. https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10157042323984367&set=a.10153401698569367.1073741826.543474366&type=3. E olha que eu sou um crítico, um questionador, que é muito diferente de reclamar. Quem só reclama não chega em lugar algum e acha que não tem sorte. Ninguém é obrigado a participar do site.

Comment: A participação do [Renan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4808/renan) no site teve um papel fundamental na contratação dele aqui na empresa que eu trabalho, entretanto não sei se isso se encaixa como sendo algo bom ou ruim que aconteceu para ele :P Mas definitivamente o site fez alguma diferença na vida dele

Comment: O [Cigano](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2999/cigano-morrison-mendez) tb já repassou vários freelas para usuários do site. O site não é só sobre perguntar, responder e ganhar pontos, é sobre networking, você cria uma comunidade de pessoas que falam a _mesma lingua_ para elas discutirem N assuntos, se encontrar, trabalhar, beber cerveja, etc.. reputação é um detalhe que ajuda a formar a comunidade e tb q é divertido :D

Comment: @Math vou mandar isso pro seu chefe :P

Comment: @Maniero já pleiteando um aumento :)

Answer (score 7):

Votei positivo para sua pergunta pois, apesar do tom de provocação, é uma pergunta que muitos desenvolvedores fazem em sigilo.

O site do Stack Overflow entra no conceito de ***gamification***. A ideia é dar um incentivo através de pontos e conquistas para os usuários continuarem ativos e colaborando, como se fosse um jogo.

Contudo, para muitos o site vai além disto. Existe um espírito natural em alguns de **colaboração** ou, até mesmo, de sermos apenas **justos** com o que o mundo já nos devolveu. É isto que faz com que tenhamos tantas ferramentas gratuitas, Wikipédia, etc. Enfim, desconhecidos se ajudando, cada um com sua própria desculpa para isto.

Eu mesmo era viciado em fóruns de Internet desde os 14 anos, ajudando desconhecidos em fóruns de hardware e software (Linux) em troca de absolutamente nada, pois a única coisa que você tinha de gratificação era o "obrigado" das pessoas e, vindo do próprio fórum, talvez um título legal ao lado do seu apelido, conforme a quantidade de mensagens que tinha no fórum.

Porém, o que mais me fez um colaborador do Stack Overflow foi retribuir para a comunidade o que site já me deu. Em sempre recomendo isto para os desenvolvedores com que trabalho: crie uma conta no SO e faça o mínimo, votando nas perguntas e respostas que te ajudam.

Também confesso que é gratificante ouvir de colegas e ex-colegas de trabalho que uma pergunta ou resposta minha já ajudaram eles. Esta parte entra o **ego** (somos seres humanos, afinal), pois não há dúvidas que é bom ouvir elogios neste sentido e ter uma boa reputação pela quantidade de pontos que tem no SO, pois não é fácil. Eu fico feliz com cada "up" que ganho.

Voltando ao Stack Overflow, o site une bem os conceitos de **gamification** e **colaboração**. E agora ainda podemos aliar isto ao perfil **profissional** do colaborador no Stack Overflow, pois usuários ativos no Stack Overflow são muito bem quistos nas empresas e, principalmente, dentre os desenvolvedores. Já soube de usuários que conseguiram ótimos empregos graças ao site, mas isto é mais comum lá fora do que aqui no Brasil.

Recentemente fiz um artigo no [meu blog](https://qualidadegarantida.blogspot.com/2018/02/por-que-todo-desenvolvedor-deveria-ter.html) falando exatamente dos motivos de contribuir para o Stack Overflow:

> O site consegue estar sempre muito ativo por três motivos: senso de comunidade, gamification e ofertas de trabalho.

Lá no artigo explico com mais detalhes cada um dos motivos.

Comment: Isso mesmo.....